# Wordpress не дружит с gulp browserSync, почему?

Tags: wordpress, gulp, browsersync

Есть установленный Open Server
Есть проект на Wordpress, который находится в папке localhost/wp/
Есть папка gulp на рабочем столе, которая, соответсвенно, настроена под сборку проектов. Там используется browsersync, который при таске 'watch' открывает сайт по адресу localhost:8000/src/

Если я просто перемещаю все файлы из localhost/wp/ в gulp/src , то при открытии сайта выдает ошибку `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` и тд. 
Если же я пытаюсь установить Wordpress с нуля в папку gulp/src , то при установке на шаге с данными базы sql выпадает ошибка 'На сайте возникли временные проблемы технического характера.' и не дает закончить установку . Если же создать файл wp-config.php вручную и добавить базу данных localhost, то снова на странице выпадает ошибка
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` ,
а в консоли пишется

```
127.0.0.1:50565 [200]: /src/ - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\Users\
```

В чем может быть проблема ? Благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Приложите содержимое вашего gulpfile.js, нужно для начала убедится что вы правильно настроили browsersync.

правильно настроенный browsersync должен проксить ваш Open server домен

```js
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: "domain"
    })
});
```